# C++ STL std::random_shuffle cannot pass custom random number generator

Tags: c++, random, stl

I want to random_shuffle a vector (I know that random_shuffle is depreciated), but I get a compile error when I pass my custom random function which I copied from another thread on here.  Can someone show me how to call random_shuffle using the random number generator posted below?

```
random_shuffle(defects.begin(), defects.end(), xorshf96);

static unsigned int x=123456789, y=362436069, z=521288629;

unsigned int xorshf96(void) {          //period 2^96-1
    unsigned int t;
    x ^= x << 16;
    x ^= x >> 5;
    x ^= x << 1;

    t = x;
    x = y;
    y = z;
    z = t ^ x ^ y;

    return z;
}
```

Comment: The random generator itself doesn't compile. `x`, `y`, and `z` are not defined.

Comment: @Galik, yes, you're correct.  I fixed the code above by declaring x, y, z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xorshf96` does not meet the requirements of the `RandomFunc` argument to [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle):

> `r`   -   function object returning a randomly chosen value of type convertible to `std::iterator_traits<RandomIt>::difference_type` in the interval `[0,n)` if invoked as `r(n)`

It must take an argument and return a random number less than it. The function is in implementation of the [Knuth Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) and that is how that algorithm works.

As a sample fix, you could provide:

```
unsigned int xorshf96_fixed(int n)
{
    return xorshf96() % n;
}

random_shuffle(defects.begin(), defects.end(), xorshf96_fixed);
```

Comment: `xorshf96() % n` is broken for most values of `n`. The fact that it's so hard to get it right is why that overload of `random_shuffle` was deprecated and removed.

Comment: @T.C. Yeah, I didn't mean for that to be a "this is a correct solution", more like "this is a function that meets the required semantics."